# Map performance with polylines containing many thousands of points

Tags: ios, polyline, mapbox-gl

The application we are developing needs to show historic movement data consisting of hundreds of thousands of points. Performance degrades as the number of points per polyline increases, or the number of polylines increases. What is the best way of improving performance in this instance?

Perhaps somehow baking the polylines into maptiles and including these as additional layers? We are currently targeting iOS9+, using ios-v3.2.0.